# How to Observe on change object Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have RecyclerView with element within object. I want to update my recyclerView if my list updates. How to observe on change of list?

**BasketStorage**

```
object BasketStorage {
    var listOfBasket:List<ServicesBasketModel> = listOf()
}
```

Comment: Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter when the list gets updated...

Comment: i have on adapter some mhetod to delete element which element deletes from mysql db

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post the relevant code? I mean the adapter and the parts where you add or remove items to/from the list.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Androidx, you can hold the var in a [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) instance and make the RecyclerView/Adapter observe it.

```
object BasketStorage {
    val listOfBasket = LiveData<List<ServicesBasketModel>>(listOf())
}
```

From within RecyclerView/Fragment code, you can observe it as follows

```
BasketStorage.listOfBasket.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    // Do something upon change
})
```

If you need mutability, do take a look at [MutableLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData). If you're getting a list from database, you can use [Room](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/index.html?index=..%2F..index#6) return a `LiveData` instance for you.

Comment: this is good variant, but i got an error ```Cannot create an instance of an abstract class```
maybe its because servicesBasketModel it is data class?

Comment: @КостянтинЛотиш Can you please show what the `ServicesBasketModel` is? Data class shouldn't be a problem. In addition to that, you will have to add the `implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'` dependency in your module level build.gradle.